# How can I tell if I nested microdata correctly within my code?

Tags: html, microdata

I am new to microdata, and have to try and put together an assignment.

It requires "At least one itemtype should be embedded (or nested) in another itemtype: the value for at least one itemprop should itself be another itemtype with its own set of properties."

The code I came up with is this:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person">
  <div style="white-space: pre-wrap;">
    <span itemprop="description">
Since I am still in my <span itemprop="knowsAbout">library and information science program</span>, I do not have as many finished projects as I wish to showcase here.
    </span>
    I have been performing coursework on reference and information services, information organization (including metadata), and an introduction to technologies that are used in the library sciences field, such as database management.
    <div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Action">
      I have done a few <span itemprop="result">library science projects</span> over the last year that have been recently completed. Actually, this<span itemprop="result"> early version of my website</span> you are on is one of them! I programmed this
      myself over the course of several days using a combination of HTML and CSS to create this website experience.</div>
    <div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/CreativeWork">
      Another project I have worked on is a <a itemprop="exampleOfWork" href="link_insert_here" target="_blank">LibGuide</a> (a library research guide) for LGBTQ+ characters in Comic Books and Graphic Novels. I have also created several learning aids.
      First is an example of a <a itemprop="exampleOfWork" href="handout.pdf" target="_blank">handout</a> I created discussing some basic information on virtual machines. This is an example of a <a itemprop="exampleOfWork" href="link_insert_here" target="_blank">video tutorial</a>      I created on how to sign up for a Local Public Library eCard.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure I nested everything properly, and when I use various structured testing tools it picks up my microdata. While it seems right, I just can't tell.

Comment: @Ori Thank you for editing my code. Is the microdata correctly nested as mentioned in my post?

Comment: Have you tried the schema.org validation tool https://validator.schema.org/